# How to set different alignment for Name/Title in ModernCV?

Tags: vertical-alignment, moderncv

I'm trying to write my CV using ModernCV template.

As you see in the picture below, the Name/Title section at the left-top of the first page in this template is **bottom-aligned** to the personal information at the right-top of the first page.

[image: Bottom-Alignment]

I was just wondering how is that possible to change the alignment of Name/Title to be ***top-aligned***, or even better ***middle-aligned*** with the personal information section!?

Your great help is truly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name etc. are placed in a `\begin{minipage}[b]...\end{minipage}` and the information on the right is in a `\begin{tabular}[b]..\end{tabular}`.  You can remove or change the alignment arguments `[b]` with the patching commands from `etoolbox`.  The following will give vertical centering, which was your preferred option.
*Updated for newer versions of `moderncv`*:

[image: Sample ouptut]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}

\name{John}{Doe}
\address{Street St., 167}{8888 Town}{Country}
\phone{+1~(234)~567~890}
\homepage{xxx.ddd.cc.ee}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{{minipage}[b]}{{minipage}[c]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{{tabular}[b]}{{tabular}[c]}{}{}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Use `[t]` arguments aligns at the top, but this with respect to baselines of the first line of each box, so is often not what you expect.

Working a bit harder we get top alignment as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}

\name{John}{Doe}
\address{Street St., 167}{8888 Town}{Country}
\phone{+1~(234)~567~890}
\homepage{xxx.ddd.cc.ee}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{{minipage}[b]}{{minipage}[t]}{}{}

\newsavebox{\mytempbox}
\newlength{\mytitleoffset}
\savebox{\mytempbox}{\addressfont S}
\setlength{\mytitleoffset}{\ht\mytempbox}

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{\raggedleft\fi}{\raggedleft\fi\vspace{-\mytitleoffset}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{{tabular}[b]}{{tabular}[t]}{}{}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Note that we have measured the height of the largest character `S` in the first line of the address.  With other material in that block you would have find something appropriate to measure.

Comment: Thanks a billion. This works greatly. (Sorry that I can't vote up your answer; because I don't have enough reputation power.)

Comment: But just one question: what does [b] & [t] in \patchcmd... command mean !? (I'm newbie to LaTeX)

Comment: The first `\patchcmd` searches the first argument `\makecvtitle` for the pattern `{minipage}[b]` and replaces it with `{minipage}[t]`.  The `[b]` and `[t]` are optional arguments to the `minipage` environment specifying the vertical placement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer. Does [b] & [t] set the alignments to bottom & middle respectively !?

Comment: `[b]` is align to bottom row, `[t]` is align top row, empty centers.  Beware that the alignment is to the baselines of the rows, and that the name is printed with letters that stretch way above the standard baseline.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work anymore in 2021. First of all, the command to patch is no longer `\makecvtitle`, but rather `\makecvhead` (using classic style, from `moderncvheadi.sty`). That's easy enough to update. But even then (and I also checked by editing the style file directly, to ensure it's not a patching issue), switching to `minipage[t]` only moves the name/title further down — it looks to me like the name is then baseline-aligned with the bottom of the details box, while the title underflows it. I had to give up and use the `\vspace` solution from Jelmer.

Comment: @hheimbuerger Thank you for the comments.  Essentially it is only the macro name that has changed, top alignment was to baselines even in the old version.  I have now updated my answer to reflect the new macro and added code for the top alignment version you seek.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thank you for your continued efforts to make this word. Unfortunately, your latest suggestion only made things worse for me.
To clarify, in the default configuration, it appears that these three items are baseline-aligned to each other: name/title, address and photo. They overlap, so instead I'd want the name/title top-aligned with the photo (or something to that effect), similar to what your screenshot shows.

Comment: The `minipage` patch seems to move the name/title *below* the photo, the `tabular` patch the address box. The `vspace` seemingly top-aligns the name/title with the address box, but both are now way below the photo, and they still flow into each other, so it's all over the place now. :)
But who knows what causes this in my case. My LaTeX isn't good enough to debug it and I have a guilty conscience to take so much of your time.
So I'm okay with using Jelmer's `\vspace` solution for now. Again, thank you!

Comment: @hheimbuerger Unfortunately I don't see a photo in the posted question.  It is probably best you ask a new question giving the set-up you start with.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I think you're right, I came to the same conclusion. I'll see when I get around to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

It might be a bit hacky, a bit lame, pretty manual and you will even get a warning. Nevertheless, I will add this answer anyway, because it is really easy and often sufficient (at least for myself). You can move the name+title part with a `\vspace`:

```
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae\vspace*{20pt}}
```

The name+title part will then just move upward.

Before:
[image: before, normal]

After:
[image: after, with vspace]

Comment: This works great for the layout but makes `*20pt` appear in the resulting PDF's title. To work around this, set the PDF's title like this: `\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdftitle = {My CV}}}`

Comment: @MatthiasBraun I do not have that problem myself and I do not know why you do, but great that you have found a way around it that helps!