# How can I place name minibox on top in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

I am using **moderncv** *classic* style. This is my header. [image: Header]

I want it to be like this (first and last name aligned on top):
[image: Proper header]

How it can be achieved?

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.8,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Courier New}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\firstname{Alexander}
\familyname{Smith}
\title{Software Developer}
\mobile{+7 (123) 456-78-90}
\email{abc@def.com}

\photo[100pt][0pt]{picture}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: [My answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285134/93175) also works and is much easier, but less precise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update (`moderncv` v2.0)

With `moderncv` v2.0, we have to completely redefine `\makecvhead` with the help of the `adjustbox` package. Adding the following lines in the preamble does what you want.

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}%
  \if@details%
    \def\phonesdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \def\socialsdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \savebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}{%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \if@left\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}\fi%
      \if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
      \end{tabular}
    }\fi%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {%
        \if@left%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi%
        \color{color1}%
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
        \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
        \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}%
        \if@right%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi}%
  % name and title (pre-rendering)
  \@initializelength{\makecvheaddetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvheaddetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}%
  \@initializelength{\makecvheadpicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvheadpicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvheaddetailswidth-\makecvheadpicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadnamebox}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvheadnamewidth}%
      \if@left\raggedright\fi%
      \if@right\raggedleft\fi%
      \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
    \end{minipage}}%
  % rendering
  \if@left%
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}}%
    \hfill%
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\llap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}\fi}%
  \if@right%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
    \rlap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
  \\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvhead
\makeatother
```

Complete code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.8,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Courier New}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\firstname{Alexander}
\familyname{Smith}
\title{Software Developer}
\mobile{+7 (123) 456-78-90}
\email{abc@def.com}

\photo[100pt][0pt]{picture}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}%
  \if@details%
    \def\phonesdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \def\socialsdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \savebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}{%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \if@left\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}\fi%
      \if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
      \end{tabular}
    }\fi%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {%
        \if@left%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi%
        \color{color1}%
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
        \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
        \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}%
        \if@right%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi}%
  % name and title (pre-rendering)
  \@initializelength{\makecvheaddetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvheaddetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}%
  \@initializelength{\makecvheadpicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvheadpicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvheaddetailswidth-\makecvheadpicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadnamebox}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvheadnamewidth}%
      \if@left\raggedright\fi%
      \if@right\raggedleft\fi%
      \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
    \end{minipage}}%
  % rendering
  \if@left%
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}}%
    \hfill%
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\llap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}\fi}%
  \if@right%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
    \rlap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
  \\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvhead
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

---

### Original answer (works with older versions of `moderncv`)

We have to completely redefine `\makecvtitle`.

Add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \vspace*{0pt}
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % optional detailed information (rendering)
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-\makecvtitlenamewidth}
  \vspace*{0pt}%
  \usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.8,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Courier New}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\firstname{Alexander}
\familyname{Smith}
\title{Software Developer}
\mobile{+7 (123) 456-78-90}
\email{abc@def.com}

\photo[100pt][0pt]{picture}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \vspace*{0pt}
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % optional detailed information (rendering)
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-\makecvtitlenamewidth}
  \vspace*{0pt}%
  \usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]