# Modern CV top align photo, name and info

Tags: moderncv

I am trying to top align all of the header (name, title and contact info) of a modern CV document. I found this code

```latex
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{{minipage}[b]}{{minipage}[t]}{}{}

\newsavebox{\mytempbox}
\newlength{\mytitleoffset}
\savebox{\mytempbox}{\addressfont S}
\setlength{\mytitleoffset}{\ht\mytempbox}

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{\raggedleft\fi}{\raggedleft\fi\vspace{-\mytitleoffset}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{{tabular}[b]}{{tabular}[t]}{}{}
```

in an answer to this question [How to set different alignment for Name/Title in ModernCV?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135909/how-to-set-different-alignment-for-name-title-in-moderncv) .However, my CV contains a photo and while the top alignment for the title and contact info works they are top aligned to a point just above the bottom of the photo. How can I fix this so that the name, contact info and photo are all aligned to the top of the page.

```
Example document
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}

\name{John}{Doe}
\address{Street St., 167}{8888 Town}{Country}
\phone{+1~(234)~567~890}
\homepage{xxx.ddd.cc.ee}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{{minipage}[b]}{{minipage}[t]}{}{}

\newsavebox{\mytempbox}
\newlength{\mytitleoffset}
\savebox{\mytempbox}{\addressfont S}
\setlength{\mytitleoffset}{\ht\mytempbox}
\photo[96pt]{headshot}

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{\raggedleft\fi}{\raggedleft\fi\vspace{-\mytitleoffset}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{{tabular}[b]}{{tabular}[t]}{}{}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With a package `adjustbox` and a new `\patchcmd`.

Remark: I added a package `showframe` to see the layout, comment in the final document.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{showframe}%<-- comment inthe final document
\usepackage{adjustbox}%<< added

\moderncvstyle{classic}

\name{John}{Doe}
\address{Street St., 167}{8888 Town}{Country}
\phone{+1~(234)~567~890}
\homepage{xxx.ddd.cc.ee}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{{minipage}[b]}{{minipage}[t]}{}{}

\newsavebox{\mytempbox}
\newlength{\mytitleoffset}
\savebox{\mytempbox}{\addressfont S}
\setlength{\mytitleoffset}{\ht\mytempbox}

\photo[96pt]{example-image-a}

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{\raggedleft\fi}{\raggedleft\fi\vspace{-\mytitleoffset}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{{tabular}[b]}{{tabular}[t]}{}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%  new patchcmd
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}
{\framebox{\adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}{}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]